# Questions about Android Unit Test with gradle or android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I am writing some test cases in my project and I have bunch questions about android unit test with android studio & gradle I met in recent days and cannot get the good answers after searching.

Here are situations I have met and they are really bothering me.

Situation 1:

When I put the test cases in **androidTest** folder and run `graldew cAT` and also use the annotation `@AndroidJUnit4` for the test class. I can run the unit test and get the right results. But after I just changed the `@AndroidJUnit4` to `@MockitoJUnitRunner` (I need mock the context). The android studio or gradle cannot find any test, only tell "empty suit".

Situation 2:

When I put the test cases in **test** folder and run `graldew test` and also use the annotation `@MockitoJUnitRunner`. It can find the tests successfully. But I guess it only run locally. If the test cases dependent some native lib, it will give the failure message like: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libxx in java.library.path`

So here are questions:

**Question 1:**

It seems that we can put the test code in src/test or src/androidTest. So what are differences between these two folders?

**Question 2:**

What are differences between `gradlew cAT` and `gradle test`? Are these two commands related to folder (**test/androidTest** folder I mentioned) in projects?

**Question 3:**

In my situation,  I need write some test cases, which dependent the Context and native so. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this is actually 3 questions, it might have been best to create 3 separate SO questions. In any event, here are the answers:

**Answer 1:**

The `src/test` folder is meant for "regular" JUnit unit tests. These are tests that run in a regular JVM.

The `src/androidTest` folder is meant for any tests that require an Android device or emulator to be running. This is where your [Espresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/) tests would live.

**Answer 2:**

The command `gradlew cAT` or `gradlew connectedAndroidTest` runs any tests which require a connected device (`cAT` standing for Connected Android Test) that are in the `src/androidTest` directory, while the command `gradle test` runs just unit tests, in `src/test` directory.

**Answer 3:**

If your unit tests depend on Context, consider using [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) for your unit tests. This will give you access to Context.  Good examples for how to use Robolectric can be found in [Corey Latislaw's "Android Katas" repo](https://github.com/colabug/AndroidKatas).

**EDIT**

**Situation 1:**
I'm not sure if this is what you are experiencing, but when I have run into this "Empty test suite" error (when I clearly have tests in the directory), it was because I forgot to include the Android JUnit Test Instrumentation Runner in my module's build.gradle file. Include it in the `defaultConfig` section of your `android` section, like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kiodev.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer and great thank. About answer 2, does it mean `gradlew cAT` will only run the tests in `androidTest` folder?

Comment: You're welcome! Much appreciated if you accept it as the correct answer. Yes, `gradlew cAT` will only run tests in `androidTest` folder.

Comment: Sure.   And also can you help to explain the situation 1 I mentioned in my questions? I have no idea about the mechanism how to detect the test cases.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit my answer to include what I know about that.

Comment: I will try the solution your new edition. Thanks for investigation!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I updated my answer. I misspoke. `gradle test` *only* runs Unit Tests.  No Espresso (or other connected device) tests are run with this command.